# Hide single tab pane in QTabWidget in ui-file?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qt5

I know there is a method to hide a single tab-pane via hide(), but I want to have a tab hidden by default via the UI-file. Adding a

```
   <property name="visible">
     <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
```

to the related tab-widget did not do the trick. So what is the correct method to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tab is a *QWidget* and *QWidget* cannot be hidden from *Qt Designer*, as answered by [goetz](https://forum.qt.io/user/goetz) on the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/3719/hiding-buttons-when-designing-form-and-stopping-form-starting-maximized/3) 8 years ago:

> The property name is "visible", unfortunately it is not available in
>   Qt Designer, as it is explicitly disabled in the Qt sources:
>
> ```
> @
> // from src/gui/kernel/qwidget.h:
> Q_PROPERTY(bool visible READ isVisible WRITE setVisible DESIGNABLE false)
> @
> ```
>
> So, you're left to hide it in your C++ code, no better advice on this,
>   sorry.

The [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.h.html#QWidget) shows that this is still the case:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool visible READ isVisible WRITE setVisible DESIGNABLE false)
```

If you insist to be able to do it, try to compile Qt from sourses with `DESIGNABLE` set to `true`.